# Simulating electrical sublimation of aluminium foil

Tags: simulations, electrical-engineering, plasma-physics

When i apply high voltage (through a capacitor bank) across an aluminium foil, it gets converted into plasma. I want to simulate this process and study the properties of the plasma produced henceforth. I would then like to change my experimental parameter and see if my simulation predicts the correct output.

How do i proceed to do so?
I am an absolute beginner in plasma physics.

Answer (score 1):

That's a lofty goal for someone with no knowledge of plasma physics.  I suggest you contact a group that has already been working on this and offer their code for free use:

> Our most recent, popular and well kept up codes are on bounded plasma,
>   plasma device codes XPDP1, XPDC1, XPDS1, and XPDP2. The P, C, and S
>   mean planar, cylindrical, or spherical bounding electrodes; the 1
>   means 1d 3v and the 2 means 2d 3v. These are electrostatic, may have
>   an applied magnetic field, use many particles (like hundreds to
>   millions), particle-in-cell (PIC), and allow for collisions between
>   the charged particles (electrons and ions, + or -) and the background
>   neutrals (PCC-MCC). The electrodes are connected by an external series
>   R, L, C, source circuit, solved by Kirchhoff's laws simultaneously
>   with the internal plasma solution (Poisson's equation), The source may
>   be V(t) or I(t), may include a ramp-up (in time). XPDP2 is planar in
>   x, periodic in y or fully bounded in (x,y), driven by one or two
>   sources.
>   http://ptsg.egr.msu.edu/

And see a [list of their publications](http://ptsg.egr.msu.edu/publication.html) for more details.

Comment: How do i proceed for writing my own code.

Comment: @hrs one byte at a time.  Start by looking at ptsg code and models.